# Download excel with php and zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, excel, google-chrome, firefox, zend-framework

in my application i need to download a excel file created with some data in a db(postgresql), when i force the download sending headers

```
function createExcel($filename, $arrydata) {
$excelfile = "xlsfile://tmp/".$filename; 
$fp = fopen($excelfile, "wb");  
if (!is_resource($fp)) {  
    die("Error al crear $excelfile");  
}  
fwrite($fp, serialize($arrydata));  
fclose($fp);
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");  
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");  
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header ("Pragma: no-cache");  
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");  
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"" );

readfile($excelfile);  
error_log("headers");
```

}

it downloads but it reads it as a cvs file and ask me for formating, but when i go to `/tmp` in my browser and click the file it downloads it as an excel file and shows the data just as i have put it in the code